Nextjs: error location not shown when using class instead of className
I just created a basic nextjs template and added somewhere a class="someclass"… This produces an error (in react on must use className instead), but the error never really mentions in which file this occurs (while other syntax errors clearly mention the file). How can I change this?
Example error:
Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?
    at span
    at h1
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:242:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:347:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:158:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:153:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:228:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:16:44)
    at Lazy
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:367:11)
    at Lazy
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:242:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:347:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:158:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:153:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:228:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:16:44)
    at Lazy
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:367:11)
    at Lazy
    at body
    at html
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/ReactDevOverlay.js:87:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/hot-reloader-client.js:322:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:202:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:112:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:158:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:564:13)
    at Lazy
    at r3 (/tmp/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:18890)
    at r3 (/tmp/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:18890)
    at ServerInsertedHTMLProvider (/tmp/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:24328)

